# Does sugarcane grow faster on sand?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been playing Minecraft for a while - at first, you could only place it on sand adjacent to water, but then there was the option to grow it on dirt. I had read and always believed that sugarcane could grow on both, but would grow faster on sand. I have experienced this twice in Minecraft, once in the PC version and one in Pocket Edition. Recently, though, I read that they grow the same speed, and that several people have proven it to be that way.

I'm really confused now - could someone clear it up for me? Thanks ;)

Answer (score 13):

The base block does not change the rate at which sugarcane grows. Players have even checked the code responsible for the growth- it only checks the block above for air and the blocks below to check it isn't already 3 blocks. There is nothing which could cause a difference between the two.

**Source:** [Minecraft Wiki: Sugar Cane Talk Page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Talk:Sugar_Cane#Growing_faster_on_sand_myth)

> Contrary to popular belief, the speed of growth of sugar cane is the same, regardless of the block it is placed on.
>
> - [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sugar_Canes#Growth)

Answer (score 6):

YouTuber xisumavoid has actually covered this in his "Minecraft Myth Busting" series (you can find the video [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p1lT-xfuLRM) if you're interested).

Xisuma concludes, using science and a check of the game code, that it makes no difference what block it is planted on. So **no**, it doesn't make any difference whatsoever what block you plant it on.

Answer (score -4):

My brother and I ran some tests - we timed how long the sugarcane takes to grow on sand, dirt, grass and farmland.

Our results showed sugarcane growing faster on sand.

Comment: Please give a source or provide us with the information from the tests